Shazamio (python) can't recognize format of the audio
I am coding a script that will download music from youtube and edit its metadata (adding cover art, name, album etc.)
so here is the full code:
from blessings import Terminal
from shazamio import Shazam, Serialize
import asyncio
import yt_dlp 
import warnings
import eyed3
import requests
import urllib
import os

#temporrary
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

t = Terminal()

def download_audio(url):
    """
    Downloads an audio from youtube
    """
    
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/beyst',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
        'outtmpl': '%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    }
    filename = None
    with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        info_dict = ydl.extract_info(url, download=True)
        video_title = info_dict.get('title', None)
        print(video_title)
        filename = f"{video_title}.mp3"
        edit_metadata(filename)
        print(t.green+"Successfully Downloaded - check the local folder")
    return filename

async def recognize_audio(audio):
    shazam = Shazam()
    out = await shazam.recognize(audio)
    song_info = {}
    track_info = out["track"]
    song_info["title"] = track_info["title"]
    song_info["artist"] = track_info["subtitle"]
    song_info["img"] = track_info["images"]["coverart"]
    return song_info

def get_image(url):

    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    imagedata = response.read()
    return imagedata

def edit_metadata(audio):
    songinfo = asyncio.run(recognize_audio(audio))
    img_data = get_image(songinfo["img"])
    

    audiofile = eyed3.load(audio)
    audiofile.tag.artist = songinfo["artist"]
    audiofile.tag.title = songinfo["title"]
    audiofile.tag.images.set(type_=3, img_data=img_data, mime_type="images/jpeg", description=u"Cover art", img_url= u""+songinfo["img"])

    #renaming the file
    os.rename(audio, f'{songinfo["title"]}.mp3')

    audiofile.tag.save()

def main():
    url = input("Paste a link from YouTube to the song you want to download: ")
    #getting filename of the download
    f = download_audio(url)
    print(f)
    edit_metadata(f)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

It works ok if I use download_audio function and edit_metadata function separately. I mean when I download an audio, I stop the script and hardcode the name of the audio. Then shazamio will do its work perfect and eyed3 will edit its metadata.
here is the error it throws
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/programming/musicdownloader/main.py", line 83, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/programming/musicdownloader/main.py", line 80, in main
    edit_metadata(f)
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/programming/musicdownloader/main.py", line 61, in edit_metadata
    songinfo = asyncio.run(recognize_audio(audio))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/programming/musicdownloader/main.py", line 44, in recognize_audio
    out = await shazam.recognize(audio)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/programming/musicdownloader/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/shazamio/api.py", line 578, in recognize
    signature = await self.core_recognizer.recognize_path(data)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SignatureError: Unrecognized format

At first it downloads mp4 then converts it to webm, but then it converts to mp3. I've printed its filename after download finished and the script saves it in mp3 .

You're going to have to explain what format you're saving it in in your post, instead of only saying that you download the audio.

At first it downloads mp4 then converts it to webm, but then it converts to mp3. I've printed its filename after download finished and the script saves it in mp3 .

Please put that in your post, not in a comment. Also, just because the filename ends in .mp3 does not mean it is an mp3: when you load it in a tool that can tell you what codec an audio file really uses, what does it report? (e.g. VLC's "tools -> codec information")

So what was the problem is that i've changed filename during the process as you can see in edit_metadata function.
def edit_metadata(audio):
    songinfo = asyncio.run(recognize_audio(audio))
    img_data = get_image(songinfo["img"])
    

    audiofile = eyed3.load(audio)
    audiofile.tag.artist = songinfo["artist"]
    audiofile.tag.title = songinfo["title"]
    audiofile.tag.images.set(type_=3, img_data=img_data, mime_type="images/jpeg", description=u"Cover art", img_url= u""+songinfo["img"])

    #we gotta remove this line. we should do it in the end of the main function
    os.rename(audio, f'{songinfo["title"]}.mp3')

    audiofile.tag.save()

